# How to remove a flag in Java

Tags: java, flags

Hi I need to remove a flag in Java. I have the following constants:

```
public final static int OPTION_A = 0x0001;
public final static int OPTION_B = 0x0002;
public final static int OPTION_C = 0x0004;
public final static int OPTION_D = 0x0008;
public final static int OPTION_E = 0x0010;
public final static int DEFAULT_OPTIONS =
       OPTION_A | OPTION_B | OPTION_C | OPTION_D | OPTION_E;
```

I want to remove, for example OPTION_E from default options. Why is not the following code correct?

```
// remove option E from defaul options:
int result = DEFATUL_OPTIONS;
result |= ~OPTION_E;
```

Comment: What does the JVM tell you?  Wouldn't running it be faster than waiting for an answer to come back from SO?  You could have had this done three times by now.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`|=` performs a bitwise *or*, so you're effectively "adding" all the flags other than `OPTION_E`. You want `&=` (bitwise *and*) to say you want to *retain* all the flags other than `OPTION_E`:

```
result &= ~OPTION_E;
```

However, a better approach would be to use enums and [`EnumSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) to start with:

```
EnumSet<Option> options = EnumSet.of(Option.A, Option.B, Option.C,
                                     Option.D, Option.E);
options.remove(Option.E);
```

Comment: It has me listed as downvoting this. I think it was a mistake, and it was too long ago so now I can't undo it!

Comment: EnumSet is very verbose compared to bitwise operations. What are benefits of EnumSet that make you believe it's a better approach?

Comment: @RestInPeace: All the normal reasons that enums are better than named `int` values... mostly type safety (two `int` constants are compatible even if they're really unrelated - but two enum values aren't) and power (enums are polymorphic, can have (preferrably immutable) state etc). There was a question about that recently, but I can't immediately find it.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right about type safety and polymorphism but with EnumSet can you do stuffs like XOR easily? Could BitSet be another alternative? With BitSet you can do XOR NOR etc.

Comment: @RestInPeace: Well it's a set, so you can do set-based operations, and there's `complementOf` to help. I think the ability to do XOR and NOR operations would be a very poor reason to abandon type safety.

Comment: Dennis Ritchie is turning over in his grave (RIP).

Comment: Thanks and why using `EnumSet` is a better approach?

Comment: @ucMedia: See earlier comments.

Answer (score 10):

You must write

```
result &= ~OPTION_E;
```

Longer explanation:

You must think in bits:

```
~OPTION_E    // 0x0010 -> 0xFFEF
DEFATUL_OPTIONS //     -> 0x001F
0xFFEF | 0x001F //     -> 0xFFFF
0XFFEF & 0x001F //     -> 0x000F
```

The `OR` will never clear `1` bits, it will at most set some more.
`AND` on the other hand will clear bits.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the `and` operator instead of `or`:

```
result &= ~OPTION_E;
```

One way to think about it is that `|=` **sets** bits whereas `&=` **clears** bits:

```
result |= 1;  // set the least-significant bit
result &= ~1; // clear the least-significant bit
```